# Refreshing expiring profiles Xcode Version 4.6.1

Tags: iphone, ios, provisioning-profile, xcode4.6

Can I ask for a little advice on how best I can update my provisioning profiles that are about to expire. I re-subscribed to the developer program so that is good until 2014, but when I click "Refresh" from inside the Xcode Organiser Xcode just pauses, churns the disk and vanishes.

I seem to have trouble with this each year, I have looked on the Apple DEV portal, should I "Revoke" the "Distribition" and "Development" Certificates, recreate them and then do a "Refresh" in Xcode or is there some other way I am missing?

[image]

**EDIT:** After a bit of research I now believe this is caused by a bug in the current release of Xcode , a bug which Apple are apparently aware of.

Comment: If I had the problem I would delete all profiles from Xcode and press refresh. And if this does not work I would delete all unneeded profile within iTC and refresh again.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on 'Renew' beside each of the profiles? (Rather than refresh)?  If the profiles in your Provisioning Portal website are expiring as well, you can click on 'Renew' on the website, and then re-download each of them, double-click to install, and you should be good to go.